# Assigning invalid values to bitfields in a union

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm working with some unions in C++ and I'm trying to determine what the defined behavior for the following case is:

Say I have a union defined as follows:

```
union word_t {
   struct fields_t {
      unsigned int x      :  8;
      unsigned int y      :  8; 
      unsigned int height :  8; 
      unsigned int width  :  8;
   } fields;

     unsigned int word;
  } word;
```

And then I attempt to assign to it like this:

```
word.fields.x = 300;
```

I've experimented with this in VS2005 and it seems to mask off the out of range bits and store the valid ones, without having any adverse effects on the other fields of union. This is how I expected it would be handled, but I haven't been able to find any documentation to back it up. Is this the defined behavior, or is it implementation specific?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Please describe what behavior you was expected and what was observed. Can you provide an example code to make it even more clearer?

Comment: Why aren't you using uint8_t or unsigned char? Actually you should use uint32_t for word also. Different platforms may have different number of bits for int type.

Comment: @Tolga I suppose my bitfields were bad examples in this case. I have various unions that have fields of nonstandard length (17 bits for example)

Comment: @NickHartung So `clang` gives me this warning on your assignment `implicit truncation from 'int' to bitfield changes value from 300 to 44` but I am confused about what this has to do w/ unions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is well defined. Per the C++ standard **4.7 [conv.integral]**, operations on unsigned integral types are performed modulo `2^n` where `n` is the number of bits used to represent the type; this applies to bit fields, too. So therefore `word.fields.x = 300;` is equivalent to `word.fields.x = 44;`, since `300 == 44 (modulo 256)`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a major compiler bug for a field value overflow to affect adjacent variables, whether bit fields, ints, whatever.

The relevance of unions escapes me.

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected. 'x' variable would have the most significant 8 bits of 'word' and 'width' would have the least significant 8 bits of 'word'. Changing x would only change most significant 8 bits of 'word'. The followings has the same effect:

```
const uint16_t N = 5;

word.word = static_cast<uint32_t>(N)<<24 | (word & 0x00FFFFFF);
word.x = N;
```

It is not implementation specific.